# How can I read a binary file that contains xml in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a binary file containing contours of DICOM image for MRI (exported from cvi42 software), I want to convert it to XML format.

```
with open('myfile.cvi42ws','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(f.tell())
    print(data)
>> 177349
>> b'x\x9c\xec\x9d\x07`\\\xc5\xf1\xff\x9fD1-`\x08!\x84_B\x1cZH!Q\xb9 ...
```

When I run decode method I got this error:

> data.decode()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: So you call `data.decode()` and get the error? If its binary data there is no reason to expect that it would decode into text. Python couldn't assemble random binary data into a unicode code point. You'll need to know about the format of the file and hopefully find a parser for it.

Comment: are you sure this file is in `UTF-8`? Maybe it is `Latin1` or something different. And if this is really bytes data then you shouldn't decode it because you always can be number which is not char.

Comment: I searched DICOM and came up with a python module https://pydicom.github.io/. I've never used it but it seems like a good place to start.

Comment: It there a reason to expect that this file contains XML?

Comment: If the hex dump you show is the start of the file you want to read, this does not look like valid DICOM - DICOM files start with a bunch of binary zeros (neither is it XML, of course). It may be the binary representation of the contour coordinates - you have to check the documentation and find out what kind of files are generated before trying to read them.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for your comment. I am trying to use this [code](https://github.com/baiwenjia/ukbb_cardiac/blob/master/data/convert_data_ukbb2964.py) that has used .cvi42wsx (containing XML) files, but my file is .cvi42ws which as you said seems different.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you. In the only reference that I had for this task [(link)](https://github.com/baiwenjia/ukbb_cardiac/blob/master/data/convert_data_ukbb2964.py), it is mentioned that contour files are in XML. I have had tried [pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/) but it did not work.

Comment: I would look for a tool to convert cv42ws to cvs42wsx. I don't know the software, though...

Comment: Just poking around, there is a [DICOM Standard](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part01.html) that will suck your soul from your body before you can figure it out - but it looks binary to me. There is a (DICOM XML proposal)[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3043771/#:~:text=The%20XML%2Dbased%20DICOM%20data,resulted%20from%20this%20new%20format.] + (DICOM to XML converter)[https://support.dcmtk.org/docs-dcmrt/dcm2xml.html]. This file may be compressed xml or convertable to xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.
Here is the answer I got from the cvi42 software producer company:

"The cvi42ws file format is not decodable. This file format is used only to transfer the saved cvi workspaces between different workstations. So it can be saved on one cvi42 workstation and then imported to another cvi42 workstation, but the contents are not decodable, and it is not possible to convert it to cvi42wsx.
The  cvi42wsx format can be on the other hand decoded. However, Circle does not provide the users with this file format, as it contains very sensitive information about the algorithms employed in cvi42."

Answer (score 0):

I open this file as text and looking for point x and y.
then plot contours. I looking for register DICOM with contours.